# The intersection Grassmanian of $n-k$-planes and Grassmanian of $k$-planes

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, manifolds, grassmannian

I am reading a paper that I don't understand some parts of it.

Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix, which its char poly is irreducible. Then, the paper said we need to check "for or every pair of $A$-invariant,  $F \in Gr(k)$ and $F^{\prime} \in Gr(4-k)$, $A(F) \cap F^{'}=\{0\},"$ which $Gr(k)$ is a Grassmanian of $k$-planes of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

My attempt and questions:

Since the char poly is irreducible, any invariant subspaces are the span of eigenvectors. Let us check the above equation for the eigenspace $H \in Gr(1)$ and $H^{'} \in Gr(3),$ which is the span of three eigenvectors. $A(H)$ is a $4 \times 1$ matrix, but $H^{'}$ is a $3 \times 4$ matrix, what does it mean about their intersection?

I would really appreciate it if one give an example for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's weird to me that, by assumption, $F$ and $F'$ are $A$-invariant, but then $A(F)\cap F'$ is computed.  Why not $F\cap F'$?  To answer your question, $A(H)$  is a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $A(H')$ is a three-dimensional subspace.  So it make sense to ask where they intersect.  Note that you'll never get an empty intersection: all subspaces intersect at $\{0\}$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito : Thank you very much for your comment. Sorry, I meant their intersection is $\{0\}.$ I can imagine it but I can not write it properly. Because I want to write a Python script for it, and I need to understand it. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: and also how $A$ acts on $H^{'}$ as $H^{'}$ is the span of three vectors.

Comment: You apply $A$ to each of the three vectors and then take their span.  (Really, you can apply $A$ to *any* three linearly independent vectors in $H'$ and take their span.  You get the same answer either way.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito : Thank you very much! I am trying to write a code for it.